# Kubernetes HPA fails to detect a successfully published custom metric from Stackdriver

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to scale a Kubernetes `Deployment` using a `HorizontalPodAutoscaler`, which listens to a custom metrics through Stackdriver.

I'm having a GKE cluster, with a Stackdriver adapter enabled.
I'm able to publish the custom metric type to Stackdriver, and following is the way it's being displayed in Stackdriver's Metric Explorer.

[image]

[image]

This is how I have defined my `HPA`:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: example-hpa
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metricName: custom.googleapis.com|worker_pod_metrics|baz
      targetValue: 400
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: test-app-group-1-1
```

After successfully creating `example-hpa`, executing `kubectl get hpa example-hpa`, always shows `TARGETS` as `<unknown>`, and never detects the value from custom metrics.

```
NAME          REFERENCE                       TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
example-hpa   Deployment/test-app-group-1-1   <unknown>/400   1         10        1          18m
```

I'm using a Java client which runs *locally* to publish my custom metrics.
I have given the appropriate resource labels as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_gke_container) (hard coded - so that it can run without a problem in local environment). I have followed [this document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#monitoring_write_timeseries-java) to create the Java client.

```java
private static MonitoredResource prepareMonitoredResourceDescriptor() {
        Map<String, String> resourceLabels = new HashMap<>();
        resourceLabels.put("project_id", "<<<my-project-id>>>);
        resourceLabels.put("pod_id", "<my pod UID>");
        resourceLabels.put("container_name", "");
        resourceLabels.put("zone", "asia-southeast1-b");
        resourceLabels.put("cluster_name", "my-cluster");
        resourceLabels.put("namespace_id", "mynamespace");
        resourceLabels.put("instance_id", "");

        return MonitoredResource.newBuilder()
                .setType("gke_container")
                .putAllLabels(resourceLabels)
                .build();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong in the above-mentioned steps please? Thank you in advance for any answers provided!

---

**EDIT [RESOLVED]**:
I think I have had some misconfigurations, since `kubectl describe hpa [NAME] --v=9` showed me some `403` status code, as well as I was using `type: External` instead of `type: Pods` (Thanks [MWZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11102471/mwz) for your answer, pointing out this mistake).

I managed to fix it by creating a new project, a new service account, and a new GKE cluster (basically everything from the beginning again). Then I changed my yaml file as follows, exactly as [this document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-autoscaling) explains.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: test-app-group-1-1
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: test-app-group-1-1
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Pods                 # Earlier this was type: External
    pods:                      # Earlier this was external:
      metricName: baz                               # metricName: custom.googleapis.com|worker_pod_metrics|baz
      targetAverageValue: 20
```

I'm now exporting as `custom.googleapis.com/baz`, and NOT as `custom.googleapis.com/worker_pod_metrics/baz`. Also, now I'm explicitly specifying the `namespace` for my HPA in the yaml.

Comment: By default HPA uses cpu from `metric-server` in kubernetes. K8s doesn't know whatever the metrics are you using. You need deploy custom adapter/metric-server like. Check for reference https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-autoscaling-custom-metrics/

Comment: I have already enabled the [Stackdriver adapter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/tree/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter#configure-cluster) (I'm using the _legacy resource model_). Is there anything else I'm getting wrong please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can see your custom metric in Stackdriver GUI I'm guessing metrics are correctly exported. Based on [Autoscaling Deployments with Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-autoscaling) I believe you wrongly defined metric to be used by HPA to scale the deployment.

Please try using this YAML:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: example-hpa
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: baz
      targetAverageValue: 400
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: test-app-group-1-1
```

Please have in mind that:

> The HPA uses the metrics to compute an average and compare it to the
>   target average value. In the application-to-Stackdriver export
>   example, a Deployment contains Pods that export metric. The following
>   manifest file describes a HorizontalPodAutoscaler object that scales a
>   Deployment based on the target average value for the metric.

Troubleshooting steps described on the [page above](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-autoscaling) can also be useful.

***Side-note***
Since above HPA is using beta API `autoscaling/v2beta1` I got error when running `kubectl describe hpa [DEPLOYMENT_NAME]`. I ran `kubectl describe hpa [DEPLOYMENT_NAME] --v=9` and got response in JSON.

Comment: I had also tried this approach of `type: Pods` instead of `type: External`, but it didn't work for some reason. However, I managed to make it work by creating a new project, a new service account, and a new cluster, and using `type: Pods`. Thanks for your answer :) . I think that, there might have been mistakes in my role configurations previously.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice to put some unique labels to target your metrics. Right now, based on metrics labelled in your java client, only `pod_id` looks unique which can't be used due to its stateless nature.

So, I would suggest you try introducing a deployment/metrics wide unqiue identifier.

```
resourceLabels.put("<identifier>", "<could-be-deployment-name>");
```

After this, you can try modifying your HPA with something similar to following:

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: example-hpa
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metricName: custom.googleapis.com|worker_pod_metrics|baz
      metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          # define labels to target
          metric.labels.identifier: <deployment-name>
      # scale +1 whenever it crosses multiples of mentioned value
      targetAverageValue: "400"
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: test-app-group-1-1
```

Apart from this, this setup has no issues and should work smooth.

Helper command to see what metrics are exposed to HPA :

```
 kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/custom.googleapis.com|worker_pod_metrics|baz" | jq
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion!